# Detecting empty object in action method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

If I have the following model and action:

```
public class Filters
{
    public string Keyword {get;set;}
    public int ArticleId {get;set;}
}

public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Full(Filters filters)
    {
        ...

        return View();
    }
}
```

If you route to the `Full` action with no querystring or form variables to populate the values in `filters` you simply get a `new Filters()`.

I need to incur a situation where I know where this was the case, or if the querystring/form variables contributed to populating `filters`.

I thought I could use polymorphism, like:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Full()
    {
        var filters = <Perhaps read out of session state>

        return Full(filters);
    }

    public ActionResult Full(Filters filters)
    {
        ...

        return View();
    }
}
```

but this does not work (ambiguous). I wrote an extension method to object that simply checks if all public properties are the default value, but it feels like there should be a better way.

Comment: As I state, have already implimented that for now. It does work.

Comment: yes - I just read that part :).  But I don't see it as being an issue as that essentially says the object is "empty", or its' equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Does setting the default value work?

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Full(Filters filters = null)
    {
        if (filters == null)
        {
            //nothing passed in
        }
        else
        {
            //do some work
        }

        return View();
    }
 }
```

Thought this would work, but can't test it right now.

**Edit**:

Seems odd it doesn't work if you're really not passing anything in, but if you're looking for maybe a more elegant way to check for defaults, you could create a public static readonly field on Filter called Empty then your checking code could be very readable like

```
if (filters == Filters.Empty)
{ 
    //passed in with nothing
}
```

Similar to `string.Empty`.

Comment: No, still get a default `Filters`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you add a special hidden input that you can test to see whether there is data or not. It could be a `bool` that is always set to `true`. If it turns out to be `false`, no form of yours was posted.

Or use `Request.HttpMethod` to find out whether this is a `POST` or a `GET/HEAD`.